# compare sum due date with current date by condional in aggregate mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

I have some problem with aggregate, I have one collection.I have collection like code below. so on I have one field call **dueDate** compare with current Date **2018-11-16**. I need sum remaining value by compare that **current date** with **dueDate** ***totalfirstAmount from remaining*** compare no **duDate** and **dueDate** less than or equal **curren date** and another second ***totalSecondAmount from remaining*** find only **dueDate** greater **current date**

```
let myCollection=
  {
  "_id" : "001-29", 
  "tranType" : "Bill",
  "tranDate" : ISODate("2018-11-16T14:55:16.621+07:00"),    
  "vendorId" : "001-2", 
  "dueDate" : ISODate("2018-11-17T14:55:16.621+07:00"), 
  "remaining" : 45,
  "branchId" : "001",     
  },

/* 2 */
  {
  "_id" : "001-26", 
  "tranType" : "Bill",
  "tranDate" : ISODate("2018-11-15T14:22:48.138+07:00"),    
  "vendorId" : "001-9", 
  "withdrawal" : 0,
  "remaining" : 90,
  "branchId" : "001",     
  "memo" : null,    
  },

/* 3 */
  {
  "_id" : "001-18", 
  "tranType" : "Bill",
  "tranDate" : ISODate("2018-11-08T14:18:36.543+07:00"),    
  "vendorId" : "001-1", 
  "billDate" : ISODate("2018-11-15T14:18:36.543+07:00"),
  "dueDate" : ISODate("2018-11-15T14:18:36.543+07:00"), 
  "remaining" : 450,      
  "memo" : null
  },
```

I want result like below

```
"lowerDueTotalRemaining" : 540,
"overDueTotalRemaining" : 45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to get the desired result.

Pipeline stages [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) are used together with pipeline operators [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

In the collection given, a condition has to be executed to find whether the given document is overdue or lowerdue, the first part of the below query does the segregation of documents into overdue and lower due. For our grouping convenience at the next stage I have added a flag "O" for OverDue and "L" for LowerDue.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      summation: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $gte: ["$dueDate", new Date("2018-11-16")]
          },
          then: {
            overDueTotalRemaining: { $sum: "$remaining" },
            flag: "O"
          },
          else: {
            lowerDueTotalRemaining: { $sum: "$remaining" },
            flag: "L"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$summation.flag",
      lowerDueTotalRemaining: {
        $sum: "$summation.lowerDueTotalRemaining"
      },
      overDueTotalRemaining: {
        $sum: "$summation.overDueTotalRemaining"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ans: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [ "$_id", "O" ]
          },
          then: {
            "overDueTotalRemaining": "$overDueTotalRemaining"
          },
          else: {
            "lowerDueTotalRemaining": "$lowerDueTotalRemaining"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Matching answer with some extra attributes which we get while executing the above query is shown below

```
{ "_id" : "L", "ans" : { "lowerDueTotalRemaining" : 540 } }
{ "_id" : "O", "ans" : { "overDueTotalRemaining" : 45 } }
```

Comment: Sorry i confuse, in fact result like that **"lowerDueTotalRemaining" : 135, "overDueTotalRemaining" : 450**